# C# Stream и действия над ним

Tags: c#, .net

Нашел на MSDN «[Практическое руководство. Скачивание файлов с использованием FTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229711(v=vs.110).aspx)».

Все хорошо, только для чтения `Stream` используется `Streamreader` который инфу читает в виде текста. А если я качаю с FTP нетекстовый файл?

«Нашел на стеке такое решение: [Saving a file (from stream) to disk using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002834/saving-a-file-from-stream-to-disk-using-c-sharp)».

Второй ответ отмечен правильным, однако, как выяснилось, свойство `Stream.Lenght` абстрактное, да и сам класс абстрактный. В отчаянии использовал
`string str = StreamReader.ReadToEnd();` и обращение к `str.Lenght;`, чтобы узнать длину Stream, однако `Read()` всё так же не работает, выдает эксепшн `System.ObjectDisposedException`.

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>
> Object name 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

**Собственно вопросы**:

1. Пример на MSDN применим только для текстовых файлов?
2. Я по верному пути пошел, пытаясь получить с FTP не текстовую информацию, или вообще не то делаю, что надо?

Comment: Ну да, хвост примера с текстом. Просто скопируйте из стрима в файлстрим.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можете использовать что-то вроде этого кода:

```
using (var ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())    
{
   var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.GetTempFileName(), FileMode.CreateNew)
   while ((bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
   {
     fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
   }  

   fileStream.Flush();      
   fileStream.Position = 0;
   return fileStream;
}
```

Comment: +1, но вроде же есть `Stream.Copy`.

Comment: Много чего есть... Можно и MemoryStream использовать, и другие варианты, пожалуй, найдутся. Это лишь пример, который на мой взляд подходит под ситуацию.

Comment: Ого) а с CopyTo() круто вышло, забыл, что туда можно подать не только другой Stream, но  и производные от него классы)